# Need help understanding the results of the unit function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, system-limitations

I want to get Limit of the following function at $T\to 0$.
$$
Eig=\frac{8 (\eta +J \sinh (2 \beta  \eta ) \sinh (2 \beta  J)+\eta  \cosh (2 \beta  \eta ) \cosh (2 \beta  J))}{\eta  Z^2}
$$
where $Z=2 (\cosh (2 \beta  \eta )+\cosh (2 \beta  J))$, $\eta =\sqrt{B^2+J^2}$, and $\beta =\frac{1}{T}$. Both $J, B$ are reals.

I used

```
Z = 2 (Cosh[2 β J] + Cosh[2 β η]);
η = Sqrt[B^2 + J^2];
β = 1/T;
Eig = (8 (η + η Cosh[2 β η] Cosh[2 β J] + 
    J Sinh[2 β η] Sinh[2 β J]))/(Z^2 η)
Limit[Eig, T -> 0]
```

But I can't understand the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get `0` for several cases.

```
Z = 2 (Cosh[2 β J] + Cosh[2 β η])
η = Sqrt[B^2 + J^2]
β = 1/T
Eig = (8 (η + η Cosh[2 β η] Cosh[2 β J] + 
      J Sinh[2 β η] Sinh[2 β J]))/(Z^2 η)

$Assumptions = J ∈ Reals && B ∈ Reals

Limit[Eig, T -> 0] // Simplify
(*ConditionalExpression[0, J > 0 && Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] < 3 J && Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] > J]*)
```

So the limit is 0 for the above conditions.  The last condition seems like a safe bet if `J != 0`.   So try `Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] > 3 J`

```
$Assumptions = J ∈ Reals && B ∈ Reals && Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] > 3 J

Limit[Eig, T -> 0] // Simplify
ConditionalExpression[0, J < 0 && Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] + J > 0 && Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] + 3 J > 0]
```

The limit is still `0`, but it wants `J` to be negative in this case.  Try it the other way.

```
$Assumptions = J > 0 && B ∈ Reals && Sqrt[B^2 + J^2] > 3 J

Limit[Eig, T -> 0] // Simplify
(*0*)
```

And we get `0` with no further conditions.  So it looks like Mathematica thinks the limit is `0`.  You might to think of other conditions that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think you have explained to me how to deal with such cases.